# popup countdown isn't running properly in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
  // 1. Define a `GlobalKey` as part of the parent widget's state
  final _introKey = GlobalKey<IntroductionScreenState>();


  // Function to open the countdown notification window
  void _showCountdownDialog() {
    
  // Set countdown time (seconds)
    int countdownSeconds = 30;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {

            late Timer countdownTimer; // countdown timer

            // Start countdown timer
            countdownTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  if (countdownSeconds >= 0) {
                    countdownSeconds--;
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // When the countdown ends, close the notification window.
                    _introKey.currentState?.next(); // Onboarding Go to next page
                    countdownTimer.cancel(); // timer ends
                  }
                });
              } else {
                // The widget is no longer in the tree, cancel the timer
                countdownTimer.cancel();
              }
            });


            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Alarm'),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(Let's start measuring. Automatically closes in ${countdownSeconds} seconds.',),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text('Time remaining: ${countdownSeconds} seconds',),
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    countdownTimer.cancel();
                  },
                  child: Text('close'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the timer when the page is disposed
    super.dispose();
  }
```

In Flutter, I would like to use a dialog window within onboarding to move to the next page when a countdown is displayed and I press the OK button. However, the time goes down like this: `30. 27. 23. 16...` and then the following error comes out.

What should I do?

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#e9652 Key Created by default](dirty, dependencies: [HeroControllerScope, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: NavigatorState#0d8cf(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5495 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
An error occurred..
```

Comment: can u elaborate ? like what u wanna achieve image

Comment: countdownTimer is start multiple time. i need full code file to check issue,

Answer (score 0):

Your Timer was messed up as it was somehow called to build a number of times within the methods that you've put it in. If you rework the code like this, it will work (I've put it in a widget I could test to reproduce the error you've described and to repair it):

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({super.key});
  @override
  State<Page> createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  Timer? countdownTimer;

  void _showCountdownDialog() {
    // Set countdown time (seconds)
    int countdownSeconds = 30;
    
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            countdownTimer?.cancel();
            // Start countdown timer
            countdownTimer =
                Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {
              if (mounted) {
                setState(() {
                  if (countdownSeconds >= 0) {
                    countdownSeconds--;
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(
                        context); // When the countdown ends, close the notification window.
                    // _introKey.currentState?.next(); // Onboarding Go to next page
                    countdownTimer?.cancel(); // timer ends
                  }
                });
              } else {
                // The widget is no longer in the tree, cancel the timer
                countdownTimer?.cancel();
              }
            });

            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Alarm'),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Let\'s start measuring. Automatically closes in $countdownSeconds seconds.',
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text(
                    'Time remaining: $countdownSeconds seconds',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    countdownTimer?.cancel();
                  },
                  child: const Text('close'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Test'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _showCountdownDialog,
        child: const Icon(Icons.start),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```